# BigQuery NOT IN is not working with subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery I have subquery like this:

```sql
SELECT country, city, count(cases) as total_cases 
FROM Table1 
where country = 'US'
AND country || city NOT IN (SELECT distinct country || city 
FROM Tablex)
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

But I see given below error:

"Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

### I tried with

```sql
WITH Alias_table1 AS (Query 1),

Alias_table2 AS (Query 2),

query as (Select * from Alias_Table1
LEFT JOIN Alias_Tabl2
ON Alias_Table1.ID = Alias_Table2.ID
WHERE Alias_Table2 IS NULL)

SELECT * FROM query
```

Comment: Your 2nd query that uses a CTE should work. Did you encounter any error on your 2nd query?

Comment: If I seperate subqueries then these queries are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out `Query 1` with `Query 2`, you can try [`ANTI LEFT JOIN`](https://towardsdatascience.com/take-your-sql-from-good-to-great-part-3-687d797d1ede)
(the possible use case would be `query 1` has **users** and `query 2` has **whitelists**).

```
WITH
alias_table1 AS (
    -- Query 1
),
alias_table2 AS (
    -- Query 2
),
query as (
    Select *
    FROM alias_Table1
    LEFT JOIN alias_Tabl2 USING (ID)
    WHERE alias_Table2.ID IS NULL  -- <- ****
    -- WHERE alias_Table2 IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM query
;
```

---

[image]

Comment: 1. Can you explain why you mentioned WHERE clause two times ? 2. Other is USING (ID) so which table ID you are refering ?

Comment: 3. Why IN () is like this ?

Comment: 1. One `WHERE` clause is commented out to highlight the differences. 2. [`USING (ID)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using_clause) is exactly equal to `ON Alias_Table1.ID = Alias_Table2.ID` if the column names are shared.

Comment: 3. Ohh ... that was a typo.